# carddav caldav - Sync in AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, caldav, carddav

I am trying to sync Google Contacts and Calendar in my proprietary application which is based on AppEngine (java).

I have heard about carddav and caldav but I am still not sure how do we sync them two way.

There are few libraries sardine but none of them talk about sync.

I am interested in knowing how well the solution scales especially as we envision that we will land up having thousands of contacts per EACH user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of libraries, you can have a look at Calconnect [list of implementations](http://calconnect.org/caldav/implementations/librariestools.html).

If you need a scalable syncing solution, you want to leverage [RFC 6578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6578) (Collection Synchronization for WebDAV).